# What's the context of "performance" or "performances" in this case?

Tags: grammatical-number

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41907) explains the singular and plural of performance depends on the contex.  One person answers that regarding algorithms, it's always singular, but perhaps other people disagreed.  Here's the passage.

> In the classical model of computation, the state-of-the-art in
>   factoring is a composition of four algorithms. **Due to their
>   performance,** they are executed in a specific order in the search
>   for a non-trivial factor of the composite number one wishes to factor.

Should it be "due to their **performances**"?

What makes it difficult for me in this case is the presence of "their".  So I'm not sure this passage can be put in the singular as Peter Shor [recommends](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/41913/338395).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance) uses the plural in one case, but that example doesn't clarify what should be done in this case.

In this context, I'm inclined to say it should be singular because the performance of algorithms is in many ways a measure of how successful they are, determining the context, but I'm not sure.  What would you say is the context here of this case?

The text could be written to "Due to their complexity classes, [...]" and then plural would be a necessity.  But I'm in the interested in the question asked, not in how it could be rewritten.

Comment: Did you find no relevant examples in any dictionaries?

Comment: I've checked the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/performances), but it doesn't seem to offer nothing on the matter.  Nevertheless, the question has been completely reworded.  Thank you!

Comment: Performance is a non-count noun when used in this context.  Performance is used a count noun when referring to musical performances.  When talking about performance from a computer, an algorithm it is considered non-count.

Comment: So, okay, then my understand is that, in the context of algorithms, it's always singular, like Peter Shor said.  I'd it this as an answer.

Comment: Actors have performances; algorithms, performance. And that’s not the OED; [this is](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/140783).